# SQL Server Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create this database with the following relations in SQL Server and I get this error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Consumable' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_*Recipe*_Ingredie__59FA5E80'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code;

```
CREATE TABLE Consumable
(
    c_ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    Amount int,
    Unit varchar(8) NOT NULL CHECK (unit IN ('ml', 'g', 'pieces', 'unknown')),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Consumable PRIMARY KEY (c_ID, Name)
)

CREATE TABLE Recipe
(
    Name varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Type varchar(32),
    Description varchar(512),
    IngredientsID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Consumable(c_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE Kitchen
(
    K_ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    IngredientsID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Consumable(c_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: PK (c_ID, Name) not a candidate for FK (IngredientsID). The candidate must be identical.

Answer (score 1):

**Read the error message!**

It's pretty clear: the foreign key you're trying to set up from `Recipe.IngredientsID` doesn't reference the **primary key** of your target table (`Consumable` - primary key is `(c_ID, Name)` - not just `c_ID` ....)

To fix this: you must reference **the whole** compound PK on your target table (e.g. you must have **both columns** of `PK_Consumable` in your child table in order to reference it

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe
(
    Name varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Type varchar(32),
    Description varchar(512),
    IngredientsID int NOT NULL,
    IngredientsName varchar(32) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Recipe_Consumable 
    FOREIGN KEY (IngredientsID, IngredientsName) 
    REFERENCES Consumable(c_ID, Name) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Any foreign key can only ever reference **the WHOLE primary key** of a parent table - or a unique constraint (again: all columns involved in that unique constraint). You cannot just simply refer to an arbitrary column (or set of columns) in your parent table.

Comment: What would the child table look like? One Recipe should contain multiple Consumables and that's where I'm stuck. With a table like Ingredients(IngredientsID, c_ID) what would the PK be? IngredientsID has a one-to-many relationship with c_ID. @marc_s

Comment: @nickvanderbeek: I showed what your `Recipe` table must look like in my answer ....

Comment: Also: it's not clear why your PK on `Ingredients` isn't just on `C_ID` - that *sounds* like an ID - wouldn't that be unique for each row already? Why do you need to include the `Name` into the primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Your Pk is a composite PK and so c_id is not necessarily unique and thus cannot be used in an FK relationship.

You have several choices depending that you had. If you will not have multiple of c_id in the consumables table than you can create a unique index on it and you should be able to create the Fk. BUt in that case really why are you using a compositer OK? The other choice you have in this situation is to make just the c_id the PK and then put a unique index on Name. Never use a composite PK if you don't have to.

If the C_id will into be unique in the Consumable table, then the only choice you have is to add the name column to the Other tables. You would of course have to give it a different name in Recipe since it has a different name.

Ingredients_id doesn't make sense in the recipe table as you are going to have more than one ingredient in a recipe. You should have a child table that contains recipe ingredients.

And On Delete Cascade is a poor choice as well. Very bad thing to do to a nice innocent database. Do you really want to delete the recipes you are out of an ingredient? I don't think so.

Comment: What would the child table look like? One Recipe should contain multiple Consumables and that's where I'm stuck. With a table like Ingredients(IngredientsID, c_ID) what would the PK be? IngredientsID has a one-to-many relationship with c_ID.

Comment: REcipe ingredients with two field Recipe id (which should be the PK in the recipe table as recipes can have the same name and be different recipes,  I can think of a dozen chicken pot pie recipes off hand for instance) and Ingredient_ID (which has the FK to C_id)  the PK in a join table like this is a composite of both columns as recipes to consumable is a many to many relationship. This is one of the places where composite keys are useful and necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the input on PK for Recipe! How would the original problem with the foreign keys be solved in the case of a composite key? Wouldn't I run into the same problem as in my question? @HLGEM